# Installing packages with Anaconda on Fedora 27

Tags: python, fedora, conda

I can't seem to install any packages with the `conda` package manager on Fedora 27, specifically, I'm trying to install `pytorch`. I've tried installing it using `conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch` but it says I don't have permission, and when I try `source activate my_root` like EVERY INTERNET SOURCE tells me to do, it just errors because `source` doesn't even do the right thing.

I also tried building it from source but it gives the error that `yaml` is not installed, and I can't install it with `conda` for the same reason: `source activate my_root` is a total scam.

I can't find anything else that is remotely close to functional. How do I perform the basic task of installing a package from the internet?

Comment: What version of conda do you have, and where is it installed?

Comment: Maybe consider using Docker. There are Conda and Anaconda images available.  At least, there will be no risk to screw up your system.